# Why can we treat Cox's partial likelihood as a full likelihood?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood, regression-analysis, log-likelihood

I am doing some self study on Cox regression, and am trying to figure out how we can derive the partial likelihood for the Cox model from the full likelihood.  Generally, I know that to get a partial likelihood, we can just use proportionality, but here, this doesn't seem as intuitive.

Consider the Cox full log likelihood: 
$$l(\theta) = \sum_{i=1}^n \delta_i log h_i(T_i;\theta) - \int_0^{T_{i}}h_i(s;\theta)ds$$

where $h_i(T_i;\theta)$ is the hazard: $h_i(T_i;\theta) = h_0(t)exp(\gamma^Tw_i)$.

The corresponding partial log likelihood would be:

$$ pl(\gamma) = \sum_{i=1}^n \delta_i \bigg[\gamma^Tw_i - log \bigg\{\sum_{T_j\geq T_i}exp(\gamma^tw_j) \bigg\} \bigg] $$

Of course, the first apparent step I see is to substitute in the hazard function into the full likelihood:

$$l(\theta) = \sum_{i=1}^n \delta_i log (h_0(t)exp(\gamma^Tw_i)) - \int_0^{T_{i}}h_0(t)exp(\gamma^Tw_i)ds$$

$$ = \sum_{i=1}^n \delta_i \bigg[\gamma^Tw_i+ log (h_0(t))\bigg] - \int_0^{T_{i}}h_0(t)exp(\gamma^Tw_i)ds$$

From here, any advice in the derivation or intuition would be much appreciated!